# How to pass query string containing variable names into mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have this procedure into which I need to pass variable parameters. Problem is this: once inside the procedure, the `IN` parameter needs to pick up already created variables in order to create the final query.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MY_PROCEDURE $$
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE (
    IN sql_string TEXT
)
BEGIN
    SET @q1 := "SELECT * FROM table1";
    SET @q2 := "SELECT * FROM table2";
    
    -- capturing the string of the query from input
    SET @sql = sql_string;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
    
END$$
DELIMITER ;

-- calling the procedure
call MY_PROCEDURE('CONCAT(@q1, " WHERE id1 < 10")');
call MY_PROCEDURE('CONCAT(@q1, " WHERE id1 < 10", " UNION ", @q2, " WHERE id2 < 10")');
```

No matter what I've tried, supplying the `@` variable with the `IN` string results in a syntax error.

I have considered that having 2 groups of `PREPARE` might do the trick:
First PREPARE converts the `IN` string to actual query by expanding variables, only return the string (Is this even possible???);
Second PREPARE then runs the query on the expanded string.

Phew!!! Any help?

Comment: Forgive my lack of mysql knowledge, but wouldn't the variable `@q1` be considered "out of scope" when used within the `call procedure`? Also, please lookup the phrase "SQL Injection".

Comment: @MichaelKutz, you're probably right. The person with the "lack of mysql knowledge", I'm sure, is me. But again, that is the point of this question: to put the matter to rest, so I don't continue trying to achieve the impossible.

Comment: @ variables are set as the `SET` (or `SELECT`) is encountered.  The `CALL`, with its _use_ of `@q1` happens before the `SET @q1`.  You must switch the order.  But that means rethinking everything.